# MailChimp Subscribe Plugin

Tags: plugin-mailchimpsubscribe

A similar bug with this plugin has be brought up before.

The issue that I'm having is that the post handle *mailchimpSubscribe/list/Subscribe* doesn't seems to be working correctly. I'm wondering if this is due to any recent changes to Craft CMS? It has worked in the past but it doesn't seem to want to work now.

```
<form class="newsletter-form" action="#subscribe" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="mailchimpSubscribe/list/Subscribe">

{% if mailchimpSubscribe is defined %}
  {% if (not mailchimpSubscribe.success) and (mailchimpSubscribe.errorCode!='1000') %}
    <p>An error occured. Please try again.</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<input type="text" name="email" value="{% if (mailchimpSubscribe is defined) and (not mailchimpSubscribe.success) %}{{ mailchimpSubscribe.values.email }}{% endif %}"/>
```

After submitting the form I get

```
Unable to resolve the request "mailchimpSubscribe/list/Subscribe".
```

I thought maybe it was to do with an incorrect character that should be uppercase/lowercase but i've tried a few different combinations.

Has anyone come across the same issue recently?

Answer (score 3):

This is an obvious one, but have you checked the plugin is installed correctly? If you're working from multiple development locations, or servers then perhaps you have a discrepancy between them?

Comment: Thanks, I found that the local environment didn't have the plugin installed as i didn't think it was required due to me working from the live database (with plugin installed).

Comment: To me, its quite unusual as working from an external/live database is quite common and wouldn't I have thought that my local environment required it to be installed.

Many thanks for double checking that its not a version issue!

Comment: Glad you got your issue resolved :)

Comment: If you find out the exact issue that caused the differences between them I'd be interested to know.

Answer (score 2):

Try lowercasing the "Subscribe" part of the action URL...

```
mailchimpSubscribe/list/subscribe
```

Comment: Interesting as I have `mailchimpSubscribe/list/Subscribe` and `mailchimpSubscribe/list/CheckIfSubscribed` in use on my site...and they seem to work fine?

Comment: (And definitely working - just checked to be sure!!)

Comment: @JeremyDaalder: Yeah, it was a bit of a shot in the dark (hence the "try"). I could speculate a few reasons why case-sensitivity would be an issue, but perhaps it's not.